# SpringXD How can a processor in a stream to get data from a kafka source module

Tags: spring, stream, processor

I have the following stream defined:

```
stream create aStream –definition “kafka –zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic aTopic | aProcess"
```

My question is that how I should code aProcess so that it can receive data (in String) from the build-in kafka source module and print the data?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code.  All you need to do is specify a sink modoule in your stream definition.

stream create aStream –definition “kafka –zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic aTopic | log" --deploy

Will write it to the STDOUT of your XD Container, or you could use the File sink to write it to a file.  The only time you need to write a custom module would be to get functionality not provided by any of the out of the box source, sinks, or processors, found at 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/